# Difference between "Canvas Visitors" and "Installed Canvas Visitors" in Insights

Tags: facebook, canvas, visitors

What is the difference between "Canvas Visitors" and "Installed Canvas Visitors" in Facebook Insights?

As per my understanding, the latter gives me the number of "returning users" (in a sense) while the former should give me the number of "new users". However, new users should be equal to new installs, which is not the case. Another explanation would be that the "canvas visitors" - "installed canvas visitors" gives the new users (in which case, there is a very high bounce on my app).

Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: There's a tooltip explaining the numbers isn't there? one is the count of visitors to your app's canvas regardless of whether or not they're installed/authorised the app - the other is only those users who have installed/authorised the app

Answer (score 0):

You can go through following link

http://www.fenixapps.com/blog/facebook-apps-insights-take-a-tour-part-1/